# WeChat OAuth 2.0 User Profile via Web in Sandbox Environment

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, wechat, weixinjsbridge

I have successfully setup a Sandbox Environment for WeChat with a URL for my API Config and a JS API Secure Domain. These work as intended, allowing me to receive messages from Followers and calling APIs from Javascript pages.

However, when attempting to retrieve a user profile via the web using OAuth2 I encounter an 'Oops. Something went wrong!' message. If I use one of the supplied example links it works as intended.

http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=User_Profile_via_Web

Is it possible to test User Profile via Web in a Sandbox Environment?

Comment: Have you tried configuring the API Privileges for Obtain the user's basic information?